CSS style min-height is compatible with Email clients and browsers?
We are creating the email to send to users.
We need to add a vertical spacer in a HTML table.
We have this:
<td height="15px" style="height:.985em; line-height:.985em">&nbsp;</td>

and i suggested to use this:
<td style="height:15px; min-height:15px"></td>

My colleague says that: "Mobile gmail isn't supporting classes and responsive rules from css only inline. Desktop gmail & outlook (both versions) & apple mail supports classes & some responsive rules".
I'm I right to say that the CSS height + min-heigh will ok?
Apart from testing it on all the device/OS combinations... there is a way to verify it, at least with 99% accuracy?

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/, https://www.caniemail.com

"I'm I right to say that the CSS height + min-heigh will ok?" - what exactly is the min-height supposed to achieve here, that the height of the exact same value would not already on its own?

@CBroe According to CanIEmail, It seems that sometimes height is buggy and needs to be replaced by min-height

@CBroe
With a quick test I find out that "height" itself is not  enough, because HTML tend to adapt to used space. min-height itself is not working, both together does.
Also it's more than  10 years I found this is the safest way by practice.
This quick test I did is purely in HTML  5 page rendered in Chrome, not in an email body.
Also. set it on TD is more "robust" than on the TR, despite in theory, it should be the same. Little small tricks I learned with experience, that is why I need a precise tool/rule/reference to support my solution. (I haven't checked the links you provided yet)
